# Landescape view always in one view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my app run in landscape mode i want it to be always in one form i.e suppose the background is stackoverflow picture in this case stack will be beside the ear speaker and flow beside home button i want when the user **rotate the iphone 180 degree (still landscape mode)** now flow will be beside the ear speaker and stack beside home button NB: i need all the view rotate not only the background

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

in your view controller and return YES for any orientation you want to support.

eg:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
}
```

that will return YES for all orientations except upside down.

Comment: thanks for answer but it work 100% in simulator but not working in the device why ?

Comment: Do you have the orientation lock enabled?

Comment: how i check this ? sorry i'am new to all this stuff

Comment: Double press the home button and swipe on right the multitask bar to reveal the controls from the left side. There is an orientation lock control.

Comment: Thank you, i forgot that i have the orientation lock enabled. all work properly